# Asking the proof of Proposition 3.13 from Dummit's Abstract Algebra page 93

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading the proof of this proposition from Dummit's Abstract Algebra page 93:

[image]

At the end of the proof, it says something like this:

[image]

My question is how could be that $S_3 = \langle (1 \: 2), (2 \: 3) \rangle$?

Comment: Could you please edit the title of your question, which has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: @verret Done thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that $HK$ is a subset of $G$ that must be contained in $\langle H,K\rangle$. Moreover, by Lagrange, $|\langle H,K\rangle|$ divides $|G|$.

Now, in this case, $|HK|=4$ and $|G|=6$. So $|\langle H,K\rangle|$ must be a divisor of $6$ that is at least $4$, so it must be $6$ and  $\langle H,K\rangle=G$.

Comment: Ahh got it... $|\langle H,K\rangle|$ must divide $|G|$ is very nice!

Answer (score 2):

$S_3$ has only $6$ elements, and indeed we can make all of them with $(12)$ and $(23)$:

- $(1)(2)(3)$ is the empty product
- $(12)(3)$ is given
- $(13)(2)$ is $(12)(23)(12)$
- $(1)(23)$ is given
- $(123)$ is $(12)(23)$
- $(132)$ is $(23)(12)$

A slightly more efficient way to see this, is to remember the following theorem:

> $S_n$ is generated by an $n$-cycle and a transposition (a $2$-cycle)

Since we can get a $3$-cycle from the given generators, namely $(12)(23) = (123)$, and we have a transposition (either of the given generators will do), we must be able to generate all of $S_3$

Yet another way is to remember

> $S_n$ is generated by the set of all transpositions in $S_n$

Since we can get every transposition from the given generators (we are only missing $(13) = (12)(23)(12)$) we must be able to get all of $S_3$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks... but I'm looking for answer from more of the point of view of the proposition...